# Xamarin.Forms Initialization with DataBinding MainText

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms. When I create a Forms Xaml page, the VS2015 will automatically generate the codes like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"           
         x:Class="MyProject.CountList">

<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
...
```

I am wondering what is the meaning of the following line. It seems like data binding but I don't know what is the label trying to bind. What is the 'MainText' and where is the label?

```
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the code behind (the `CountList.xaml.cs` file). The `MainText` property should be there.

Comment: That is telling the view to bind to the `MainText` property of its `DataContext`. It will inspect the properties of what ever object is assigned to the DataContext and reflect what ever value is stored in it.

Comment: Check an introduction here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Comment: Answer is at your code behind class, if you post full code here we can answer you, but short answer is that this label is binding to a property of MainText.

Answer (score 3):

This part `Text="{Binding MainText}"` means the `Text` property of the `Label` (in this case) has a data-binding to a property called `MainText`.

This property should be available in the class that has a data-binding to this view. The most obvious way to set this class is through the code-behind and setting the `BindingContext` of the page. This can be anything. So it can be `this` to bind the code-behind to the view directly, or it can be another class which functions as a *ViewModel* or *PageModel*.

Another, less obvious way, is by using a MVVM framework. Depending on the framework the View and ViewModels (or Page and PageModels) are bound together by either setting up some mapping or by naming convention. In the latter case, if your Page is called 'MyListPage' look for a file (or rather class) named 'MyListPageModel'. At runtime the binding is done for you by the framework.

Consider this simple example based on your question. This is your page, let's call it `SimpleLabelPage.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"           
         x:Class="MyProject.CountList">

    <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

If you would right-click on the file and click 'Code' (in Visual Studio) you would go to the code-behind `SimpleLabelPage.xaml.cs`. This could look like this:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowAwesomeness
{
    public string MainText { get; set; }

    public partial class SimpleLabelPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SimpleLabelPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            MainText = "Hello from bindings!";
            BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when running the application you should see the data-bound text in the UI.

You could also move it into its own class like this:

```
public class SimpleLabelPageModel
{
    public string MainText { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your code in the code-behind to:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowAwesomeness
{
    public partial class SimpleLabelPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SimpleLabelPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            var pageModel = new SimpleLabelPageModel();
            pageModel.MainText = "Hello from bindings!";

            BindingContext = pageModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Which ultimately has the same effect, but you can separate the logic from your view this way.

That is basic data-binding 101. To read more on it, see the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/).

You might also want to look into frameworks like MvvmCross or FreshMvvm and `INotifyPropertyChanged` or use `PropertyChanged.Fody` for that.